# How to have null pointer passed when calling COM methods from PHP?

Tags: php, com, interop, com-interop

There's this method definition in COM server IDL:

```
[id( 15 )] 
HRESULT RunProcessing(
    [in, defaultvalue( 0 )] IProcessingParams* ProcessingParams,
    [in, defaultvalue( 0 )] IIndicesCollection* Indices );
```

the COM server is implemented in C++ and proper registered and the typelib created from that IDL is also proper registered.

There's a piece of PHP code that tries to invoke that method and pass "null" as first parameter and a specific object as the second parameter:

```
$processor->RunProcessing( NULL, $indices );
```

This yields

> Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 0: type mismatch'

and refers to the line with `RunProcessing()`.

What's the proper way of having a null pointer passed into a COM object method from PHP code?

Comment: You could try `$null = new VARIANT( VT_NULL );` and then pass `$null` as the first parameter?

Comment: @RamRaider Same problem. I also tried `VT_EMPTY`, `VT_UNKNOWN`, `VT_DISPATCH` and `new VARIANT()` without parameters - it's all the same.

Comment: You've got me trying to do some experiments with COM objects now ;-)